# Node api GET status request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Im fetching the `ID` and current `status` of the item, it works, but i want to do a check to see if its active or not meaning if `active: false` then return -> status 404 , message: Status not active.

My problem is i cant seem to get the active returning from the request, im new to this so maybe im understanding it wrong or making a simple mistake, thanks for help in advance.

Document:

```
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("5b3f7b2efe8d1f3ef8096dfd"),
     "name" : "Brand Name",
     "active" : false,
     "__v" : 0
}
```

Code:

```
// RETURN ACTIVE STATUS OF SINGLE BRAND FROM DATABASE

router.get('/:id/ActiveStatus', (req, res) => {
    var id = req.params.id;

    //MY ATTEMPTED TO GET THE ACTIVE STATUS = undefined  
    var status = req.query.active;
    console.log(status);

    if(status !== true){
        return res.status(404).send({message: 'Status not found.'});
    }

    if(!ObjectID.isValid(id)){
        return res.status(404).send({message: 'Invalid Object ID provided.'})
    }

    Brand.findById(id, {active: 1}).then((brand) => {
        if(!brand){
            return res.status(404).send({message: 'Error, status not active.'})
        }
            res.send({brand});
    }).catch((e) => {
        return res.status(404).send(e);
    });
});
```

Comment: What does the `console.log(status);` return?

Comment: undefined and im expecting `active: false` or `false`

Comment: Okay, do you have the `active` parameter coming (getting passed) in your URL?. Because `req.query..` will only fetch those being passed as URL params.

Comment: Can you show us fetching data from database part?

Comment: nope i dont thats the problem reading the docs i dont see anyway of doing this without it being passed through the URL as params, i was thinking if i got the id, i can get all the data based on the id.

Comment: What does this return => `var status = req.query.ActiveStatus; console.log(ActiveStatus);` ?

Comment: @DavidR ive tried that, since its just a url not passing vlues, its returning : `undefinied` , i have to get all the data asscoiated with the ID and then request the active from that which is not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//MY ATTEMPTED TO GET THE ACTIVE STATUS = undefined  
var status = req.query.active;
```

If you want to get the status parameter then according to your code, the client will have to provide it when calling your api. So the client api call should be -

```
https://<url>/<id>/ActiveStatus?active="some value"
```

After which you can access it like the way you did in your code.

```
var status = req.query.active;
```

If you want to get it from request parameters you can define your route like this

```
// RETURN ACTIVE STATUS OF SINGLE BRAND FROM DATABASE

router.get('/:id/ActiveStatus/:active', (req, res) => {
    //your code
});
```

In this case you can access it via the request parameter much like you did for the id

```
var status = req.params.active;
```

Comment: Hi man, oky so without the active paramater in the  URL im not able to see the current active state from the request? not even from the id? so ill need to write a specific HTTP request for this check is what you prefer?

Comment: If the status is not supplied with api call from client, then the only way for you to check the active status is to retrieve the resource from the database and check the active status field. In which case you can just add another check in your code which checks the brand's status field inside the callback of the database retrieval call